# Only redirect the requests for "https://localhost:8000/stripe_checkout/..."

Tags: nginx, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I develop a web product in react in my Mac. I need to run `sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=ssl/localhost-mac/cert.pem SSL_KEY_FILE=ssl/localhost-mac/key.pem ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` to launch the frontend. As a result, e.g., `https://localhost:8000/#/home` launch the home page.

I also develop the backend in My mac. In another folder, I need to run `yarn start`. Then, `https://localhost:3000` serves requests from the frontend. At the moment, the frontend and the backend work well together.

The current `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is as follows. Note that there a server block for 443; there is no server block for 8000.

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    log_format my_log '{ "time": "$time_iso8601", '
    '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
    '"status": "$status", '
    '"request": "$request", '
    '"request_method": "$request_method", '
    '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
    '"http_x_forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for", '
    '"host": "$host", '
    '"server_name": "$server_name", '
    '"upstream_address": "$upstream_addr", '
    '"upstream_status": "$upstream_status" }';

    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;

    upstream videohint {
        # server 167.172.58.156:443;
        server localhost:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost/localhost.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_stapling off;
        ssl_stapling_verify off;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "";
        proxy_ssl_name "www.videohint.com";
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        location ~ /socialLoginSuccess {
            return 301 https://$host:8000/#/socialLoginSuccess;
        }

        location ~ /auth/(.*) {
            proxy_pass https://videohint/key/auth/$1?$query_string;
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
            proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
            proxy_pass          https://localhost:8000/;
            # proxy_pass          https://www.bing.com/
            # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove socketio error
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Now, I have some special needs. I would like everything to work as before excepts requests for `https://localhost:8000/stripe_checkout/...`; I want to redirect the requests to `https://localhost:8000/stripe_checkout/...` to `https://checkout.stripe.com/...`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code **above** to the `location / {.....}`

```
location /stripe_checkout {
       proxy_pass    https://checkout.stripe.com/;
   }
```

Comment: the current server block is for 443, are you sure your modification will work for localhost:8000?

Comment: the above code will redirect all `/stripe_checkout` routes to `https://checkout.stripe.com/;`

Comment: but it's still inside `server { listen 443 ssl; ...... }`, no?

Comment: Yes. Inside the `server { listen 443 ssl; ...... }` and just above the `location / {.....}`